# How to change gpg passphrase using script?

Tags: gnupg

Using `--passphrase-fd 3`, `--pinentry-mode loopback` and `3<<<"foo bar"` works to enter passphrase, but how can one change passphase (which requires two inputs)?

Comment: Does it work when you use something like `\n` as the input?

Comment: I tried using line break… unfortunately it doesn´t work. I opened an [issue](https://dev.gnupg.org/T5575) on GnuPG’s repo.